# XML serialize Error: the type system.string may not be used in this context

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a WORK CLASS:

```
public partial class WORK
{
    Public WORK()
    {
        oId= new List<WORKID>();
    }
    // I have got WORKID obj in constructor & Get, Set variables...

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WORKID")]
    public List<WORKID> WORKID
    {
        get{}
        set{}
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class WORKID
{
    public string SERVICEORDERNO{}
    public string TECH{}
    public object APPOINTMENT{}
    //etc...
}
```

In Main class...

```
WORID owork = new WORKID();
//assigned
```

all the values to WORKID class and its Related Class.

Now the error is when serialize

```
var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WORK));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\out.xml"))
      {
          xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, owork);
      }
```

Exception:

> The type System.String may not be used in this context.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An List<> or array can't be an attribute.  Change XmlElementAttribute to XmlElement.

Comment: A missing quote (which I believe to be a typo in entering the question) was causing the formatting to break.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working copy:

```
                var x = new WORK
                {
                    WORKID = new List<WORKID>
                    {
                        new WORKID
                        {
                            APPOINTMENT = "A",
                            SERVICEORDERNO = "!",
                            TECH = ".Net"
                        },
                        new WORKID
                        {
                            APPOINTMENT = "A",
                            SERVICEORDERNO = "!",
                            TECH = ".Net"
                        }
                    }
                };

                var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WORK));
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\path\\x.xml"))
                {
                    xs.Serialize(sw, x);
                }
```

Note I ommitted all the `Attributes`

Comment: Thanks Amit, But I have identified the cause as my class set property value as XmlNode in one instance and Datetime in other.. I think if I convert Datetime to XmlNode should work fine.